# How do you create a button to "reset" the states of multiple toggle buttons to "off"?

Tags: android, button, toggle, reset

For example:

1. I have 15 toggle buttons (default state for all of them is off)
2. Say, I toggle on 6 out of the 15 toggle buttons

What I want to do is have a button that when pressed, it resets all 15 of the toggle buttons back to off so the user can start over.

I am using Java not Kotlin in the latest Android Studio

I am super new to developing apps and tried searching for my question but maybe I couldn't find the answer due to the non technical terms I used.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the checked state of the 15 buttons in a list, every time the user modifies the state of a switch you update the list at the given position.

When the user selects the reset button then you just set to false all the elements in the list.

Comment: Thanks Luis. I'm guessing the list of the 15 button's state would be stored in the activity_main.xml? What code would I need to use?

Comment: @Atom, the list of switches should be included in the MainActivity.java file, this file is the link between your activity_main.xml and the rest of your application. The activity_main.xml is a pure xml file which means you are only able to set layout components in that file (buttons, texts, etc.), then in your MainActivity.java you inflate the xml layout and link each component in the java code. As Rob mentioned in this comment, you link a switch in the activity this way: Switch switch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1); ,

Comment: In the MainActivity.java I would create the list like this: List<Boolean> switchesState = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
switchesState.add(switch1.isChecked);
switchesState.add(switch2.isChecked); add the remaining switches...

Answer (score 0):

1. In your Java code, create `Switch` objects for each of your toggle buttons and a `Button` object for your reset button:

```java
// note that the names in R.id.name must match the IDs you assigned in your XML
Switch switch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
Switch switch2 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch2);
Switch switch3 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch3);
// ...
Button resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
```

2. Create an onClick listener for your reset button and add the default values inside the `onClick` method:

```java
resetButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch1.setChecked(true);
        switch2.setChecked(false);
        switch3.setChecked(true);
        // ...
    }
});
```

See [the Android documentation for Switches](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch) for more info, or a [tutorial like this one](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-switch-on-off-button-with-examples) for more digestible/detailed step-by-step instructions.